# Detect when HTML5 audio stream breaks or pauses

Tags: javascript, cordova, streaming, html5-audio, shoutcast

I am trying to stream a Shoutcast URL using HTML5 Audio on a Cordova app.

The problem I have run into is this: There appears to be no callback that fires when an audio stream *loses connection* to the ShoutCast URL. At this stage, the audio element shows that it is playing the audio, but there is no audio.

### Code

```
Radio = {
    initialized: false,
    isBuffering: false,
    interrupted: false,
    isPlaying: false,
    media: null,
    trackName: '',
    url: 'shoutcast_url',
    initialize: function () {
        if (!this.media) {
            this.media = new Audio(this.url);

            this.media.preload = "none";

            this.media.onerror = function (e) {
                App.alert("Unable to connect to Radio");
                Radio.interrupt();
            };

            this.media.onwaiting = function (e) {
                Radio.set_buffering(true);
            };

            this.media.onplaying = function (e) {
                Radio.set_buffering(false);
            };
        }
    },
    set_buffering: function (value) {
    ...
    }
```

### Scenario

- Connect to the Internet (say, through a hotspot) and start the audio radio.
- Disconnect the hotspot from the Internet.

After the buffered content is played, the audio stops playing. But no callbacks are fired that indicate loss of connection.

- `media.networkState` is `2` (NETWORK_LOADING)
- `media.playbackRate` is `1` (Playing forward at normal rate)
- `media.readyState` is `4` (HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA)
- `media.preload` is `none`

The callbacks that I tried, (which did not fire when connection was lost) are:

- `onstalled`
- `onreset`
- `onsuspend`
- `onerror`
- `onprogress`
- `onwaiting`

**Question** - Is there an audio callback that will fire when it is unable to play the audio due to lack of connection?

If not, is there any method which will update `readyState` or `networkState`? If so, I could just set a timer to check these values.

Comment: Can you show how you listened for the events? Stalled, for example, should work, as is documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Comment: @RaymondCamden Added my current code to the question. I had the callbacks added in `initialize()`.

Comment: So did you try stalled yet? this.media.addEventListener("stalled", ...

Comment: No, I did not add an event listener. I thought that `onstalled` would function the same. Anyway, I will update the question after I try this out.

Comment: @RaymondCamden `this.media.addEventListener("stalled", ..` doesn't fire either. It fires when the media is played the first time, but it does not fire when I disconnect the Internet connection....

Comment: You got me there - sorry I can't help more.

Comment: have you tried to listen to the "ended" event? i know it doesn't make much sense since it's a stream but i had cases of wrong callbacks being triggered before

Comment: @joyrex (Sorry for the late reply) But `ended` wasn't triggered either.

Comment: @Ajoy this might be a roundabout way, but have you tried, hooking up the audio with WebAudio and analyzing that data?

Comment: @mido What interface should I use? Most of them deal with processing audio...

Comment: @Ajoy you could create an Javascript Node from the Audio Context, and listen to `onaudioprocess `, look at the buffer values, if they all remain to be zeros, you can identify the issue that way... long shot, but believe it would work

Comment: @RaymondCamden found the solution. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a supported audio stream is played using HTML5 Audio, the best way to figure out if the audio is playing is to listen to the event [timeupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate).

> The timeupdate event is fired when the time indicated by the currentTime attribute has been updated.

The event fires only when audio is being played. If the audio stops, due to any reason, `timeupdate` doesn't fire either.

**However**, browser support is not complete.

- On Android 5.0 (Chrome 48), `timeupdate` never fires nor is `currentTime` updated.
- On latest desktop browsers (Mozilla 45 and Chrome 49), `timeupdate` functions as documented.

Comment: Would you please provide more details?  I've got a Cordova app using "cordova-plugin-media" and the following code only fires once (when the stream begins).

audioStream.ontimeupdate = alert("timeupdate fired");

Comment: @AndrewBucklin `timeupdate` does not fire on Lollipop (as far as I have understood)

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure that loss of connection is actually what you want?  The audio can stop and your connection effectively lost without the underlying TCP connection actually being closed.  You could have no data for hours, effectively dead connection, but still have that TCP connection active.

Instead, I would recommend looking at the playback time.  (Your onprogress handler is also effective.)  If that isn't increasing after a timeout that you set (10 seconds or whatever is appropriate for your situation), then clear the audio player and attempt to reconnect.

Comment: I want to be notified when there is no audio being played, either because of buffering or due to loss of connection. `onwaiting` does fire just before the audio is played (because `preload` is none).

Comment: `media.duration` and `media.currentTime` are both always `0` because this is an audio URL. The callback `onprogress` does not update either.

Comment: @brad I have a similar issue with the TCP connection. I am not sure but when the internet goes down it sends only 30 requests(or 30 seconds) after that it stops sending requests but if it came back before 30 requests it starts streaming and audio play without issue. So even if the internet comes back online it doesn't play audio. What could be that limit? Here is my question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67056630/partial-audio-download-problem-when-internet-get-disconnected

Answer (score -3):

You could listen for the [online](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Online_and_offline_events) event to restart the stream:

```
window.addEventListener('online', function() {
  audio.play();
});
```

Comment: `online` event has nothing to do with audio streams.

Comment: In the scenario you laid out, the audio stream stops playing after you disconnect the internet. The 'online' event will be fired when the internet comes back online.

Comment: As long as the device is connected to a Wi-Fi, `offline` will not fire; neither would `online`. This question is for those cases where connection is lost between the WiFi router and the internet.